# How can I ensure secure communication between my browser extension and native host?

Tags: security, google-chrome-extension, chromium, named-pipes, chrome-native-messaging

I am building an app that exchanges sensitive data between the extension and the native host. I realized that communication between the 2 is done via Named Pipes [(see here)](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/extensions/api/messaging/native_process_launcher_win.cc;l=213). This means, as far as I understand, that other processes can read/write to this pipe. This can be dangerous if we have a malicious process on the end user machine, which led me to a couple of questions:

- What are the best practices to secure the communication between the extension and the NH?
- Why is chromium using named pipes instead of anonymous pipes and Would it be possible for chromium to change it to unnamed pipes?

1. Run an extension with a native host
2. Use PipeList to view the existing pipes in windows
3. You can get the native host pipe name

I expect the native host pipe to be hidden from other processes.

Note: a similar question has been asked before, but the older version may be outdated and is not precisely what I am looking for.

Comment: 1) "see here" should link to something? - 2) You mentioned a similar question that's been asked before. Can you link to it, for the sake of completeness? - 3) I have no idea what the best practices for solving this problem are, because until now, I didn't even realize it could be a problem. But I suppose you'd have to encrypt the sensitive data.

Comment: 1) thank you. 2) I can't seem to find the question using Google. I might try again later. 3) encryption might be a solution, but it requires safe key exchange, which needs to be standardized and not implemented by developers.

Comment: Chromium is open source, you can modify it. Also the communication between native messaging host and your extension is not designed with security in mind and nor is it designed to transfer huge amount of data.

Comment: I don't think you will have an issue on your own machine. You will have to hack yourself for something to go wrong.